# Does VMWare Player 3.0 require Intel-VT capable processor

Tags: vmware-player, windows-7, virtualization, dell, intel-vt-x

I have Dell Studio laptop with Intel E6600 processor, I have checked and confirmed that this processor does not have Intel-VT support. (Its available in 6670 available on Dell Vostro)
Has anyone practially used VMWare Player 3.0 on a machine/laptop with processor not having Intel-VT support.

Some references.
[Link # 1](http://www.astroarch.com/blog/?p=28)
[Link # 2](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003944)

[Edit]
I tried Virtual PC from MS and it does not work due to the absence of Intel-VT.
My OS is Windows 7 Professional 64Bit
I need to run only Windows 2003 32 bit Standard and Ubuntu, is this possible with the player 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

It should work, but you'll only be able to run 32bit OSes (at least if it's the same as VMware Server, VirtualBox, etc etc)

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 Pro 64bit, does that make a difference?

Comment: It still won't work, though. Sorry. You need the VT support to "pass through" the 64 bit instructions.

Comment: What are my options to run a VM, I wanted to run an instance of Win 2003 std and Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you saying I cannot run even 32 bit OS VM or any other OS VM at all ?

Comment: No, you'll be able to run 32 bit guest OSes, but not 64bit guest OSes

Answer (score 2):

Hardware Virtualization is not required for Workstation 7 or Player 3 for 32 bit Guests although it may be required for 64 bit Guests. It is definitely required if you intend to virtualize ESX.

The links you provided are for ESX 4.

**Edited to add:**
The [Release 3 Installation Guide](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware_player300.pdf) specifies the following:

> Processor Support for 64-Bit Guest
>   Operating Systems When you power on a
>   virtual machine with a 64-bit guest
>   operating system, VMware Player
>   performs an internal check. If the
>   host CPU is not a supported 64-bit
>   processor, you cannot power on the
>   virtual machine.
>
> VMware Player
>   supports virtual machines with 64-bit
>   guest operating systems, running on
>   host machines with the following
>   processors:
>   - Revision D or later of AMD Athlon 64, Opteron, Turion 64, and Sempron
>   - Intel Pentium 4 and Core 2 processors with EM64T and Intel
>   Virtualization Technology

Provided the OS you want to install is supported by Player 3 then you can install any 32bit Guest OS you like using that processor. Many Ubuntu versions are supported but generally VMware Tools support for the most recent releases tends to take some time. You can find the full list of supported Guest OS's in the document linked above. Unsupported OS's may still work but performance may be poor or there may just be some compatibility issues that do not affect you so its always worth a try.

Comment: I have a laptop I will just be using player 3, on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, can I run any VMs 32 bit Windows 2003 std and ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

VMware frequently does not use VT, because their technology often provides better performance than is possible with VT.  E.g., VMware Workstation allows you to enable VT use, but the default on my machine is to not use it.  In fact, usually VT needs to be enabled in the BIOS, because there are attacks on VT (and similar technologies) such as the BluePill attack that are pretty scary.

See for example this link, which is about VMware Server not needing VT:
http://communities.vmware.com/thread/191399

The links you provided are about trying to run VMware ESX server, VMware's bare-metal hypervisor (runs directly on the host machine, without a host OS), **inside** of VMware Workstation or Player.  This is a very unusual configuration, primarily used for testing ESX.  If you think about it for a moment, it will make sense that running VMware's most powerful product within one of their other products requires some special support.

As far as 32-bit and 64-bit, I think I've run 64-bit guests within my 32-bit host OS without enabling VT, but I'm not sure.  VirtualPC is not a fair comparison, because VMware basically invented x86 virtualization more than a decade ago.

Honestly, downloading and running Player will be pretty quick.  If you have an Ubuntu ISO, you can simply mount that and run it as a LiveCD within player.  Actually doing Ubuntu installation doesn't take that long.  Windows Server installation will be slower, but I would bet that it will work.

Once you've got things set up, you might look into using VMware Server, which is also free, and more powerful than VMware Player.

Comment: A VMware employee implicitly confirms that Player 3.0 does not require VT to run 32-bit guests.  On Intel hardware, 64-bit guests DO require VT.
See http://communities.vmware.com/thread/243265

Since Server 2003 is 32-bit with PAE (pretty sure), it should be ok.  Older versions of the VMware Player guide specially say that Server 2003 is supported, and do mention that VT is required for 64-bit OS's.
http://www.vmware.com/pdf/VMwarePlayerManual10.pdf

Comment: Any compelling reason for me to use VMWare Server instead of VMWare Player from the start?

Comment: Also will VMWare Server install and work on Windows 7 Pro 64bit host?

Comment: From what I can find, Server 2.0 runs on a 64-bit Windows 7 host but some people have had problems with getting the network configured.  Some people had problems with early Windows 7 betas.  Network configuration can become complicated as you try more complicated things, since you're essentially creating an entire LAN inside your host that connects to the outside world via the single Ethernet card on your host.

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/234119;jsessionid=2614969FBD886E060FC703F39F6D5D85
http://communities.vmware.com/thread/189811;jsessionid=255785BDECC7019DBA736E0141FF86AC

Comment: So you should definitely try VMware Player first, since that's supported on Windows 7.  VMware Server is a product for servers, and isn't officially supported on client OS's, although it generally just worked on previous versions of Windows.

Personally, after running Player for a little bit, Server for a year or so, and then Sun's VirtualBox for several months, I decided VMware Workstation was worth the price tag.  I still discover new features.